# How to use WatchService in Android app

Tags: java, android

I am importing `java.nio.*;` package to use `WatchService`. But its getting errors. So how can I use `watchservice` in my app?

"WatchService cannot be resolved to a type" like this i am getting .

Comment: It would be great if you told us what the errors were.

Comment: "WatchService cannot be resolved to a type" like this i am getting

Comment: [`WatchService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) was added in Java 7. It does not exist in Android since that is essentially Java 6.

Comment: Is there any way to get notifications in android when the user delete any file from sdcard?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html

Comment: I already used that fileobserver, its notifying me after operation completed (operation like delete, modify, move etc). Is it possible to get notification before deletion ?

Comment: @sri There's no way to know, on the OS level, that a deletion is coming. Even if there were, the OS wouldn't stop so that it can notify you.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  I am doing application which is similar to Dumpster in android. So thats why i am trying to get notification before deletion.But its not working. I tried with fileobserver and contentobserver also. You are saying that no way to know, but if u delete a txt/png file from any explorer Dumpster app moving that file to their own location. Like that i want to implement . Is it possible ?

Comment: Perhaps it is listening to a folder where Android puts deleted files before actually deleting them. I don't know :(